# Meaning of empty quotes in select by attribute query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

Can someone please help explain if the empty '' means something?

I am wondering if it might be inserted by typo or if you use these empty quotes to locate empty fields within the attributes.

[image: empty quotes - question]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it'll select all rows where the COMMENTS field is empty.  I just tested and it also selected rows with a single space: ' ' (tested with an .mdb feature class).

However, it will not select Null values (use IS NULL for that).

Comment: That is not precised. It will not select empty fields. Note that a single space within a field doesn't make it empty. It also valid for text type fields, and not for integers, float, etc. The IS NULL is the way to select "real" empty fields.

Comment: @mvg04 And thus a good example of how null is not zero or empty, null is *null*. Note that shapefiles, which use the dbf format, don't support null values, thus anything null they store is a space or 0. This will happen frequently when moving data back and forth between a geodatabase and a shapefile, particularly in mixed editing environments.

Comment: thanks for the note on shapefiles, I don't use them too often so I wasn't aware of that.  It seems fair to assume then that the OP has the preferred way to look for empty attribute (string) values in a shapefile.

Comment: @dof1985 That is incorrect, although I guess we need to be kind of explicit here. `''` (quotequote) is **not** the same as `' '` (quotespacequote) and the former absolutely will select empty fields whether they are strings or numbers. In a database that doesn't support null, there's no such thing as IS NULL unless something is interpreted to be that. In one that does, like a file geodatabase, a null is a special value - you can't just blank out a field and have it be null, you have to *set* null. It is entirely possible to blank (no space) either a string or numeric field in such a database.

Comment: @ChrisW, I appriciate your knowledge and experties and am aware of the meaning of NULL, but arcgis-10.2.2 have proven differently. I have too tested it before answering, and blanking a numeric or a character field in an edit session (within a GDB format) leaves NULL value. In order to get the so-called empty field, I had to add a single space, and it applied only to string values.

Comment: @dof1985 You can't just blank the (null) value, because yes, that will revert to a null. However if you enter any other value (for either data type), and then delete *that* (may need to save edits between), it *will* leave a blank/empty field. I have an open attribute table in front of me that exhibits this. It's a real nuisance when you bring shapefile data into a geodatabase and then edit/create more records, because then you end up with a mix of true null and empty records for a given field.

Comment: @ChrisW - Got it. tnx

Comment: yes, this is a really good point, because to turn a value into a real Null value you have to use field calculator.  I understand exactly what @dof1985 was getting at.